# Go socket : too many open files

Tags: sockets, http, go

When I send requests from the following code:

```
req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", "my_target:", nil)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
req.Close = true
client := http.DefaultClient
resp, err := client.Do(req)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
defer resp.Body.Close()
```

After a few hours of sending average 10 requests per minutes, I get this error:

```
socket: too many open files
```

How do I find the cause of this problem?

Am I not closing the http.Request?

I thought `req.Close = true` does that job.

Thanks!

Comment: I am running this under ubuntu 14.04 and go1.5beta1

Comment: @BravadaZadada The request is to the same host. And inside a function. Thanks

Comment: No, just this one request. Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Why are you deferring the close? Are you actually reading from this body?

```
defer resp.Body.Close()
```

Do you actually return from the current function before performing another `Get`? If not, then the `defer` will never execute, and you'll never release this connection for reuse.

`req.Close = true` is an unusual choice here, as well. This also prevents connection reuse, which is something you'd probably want rather than forbid. This doesn't automatically close the request on your side. It forces the *server* to immediately close the connection, which you would otherwise reuse. You'll hold your side open until you close it.

Typically for a simple GET request like you have here, I would just do this:

```
resp, err := http.Get("...")
if err != nil {
    panic(err) // panic seems harsh, usually you'd just return the error. But either way...
}
resp.Body.Close()
```

There's no need for a special client here. Just use the default one. It'll take care of the rest as long as you make sure to close the response body. And there's no need to complicate things with a `defer` if you're going to immediately close the body. The reason for `defer` is to make sure you close the body if you have a bunch of processing later that might return or panic on error.

Comment: Thank! I am calling this one call inside one function. What would be the best way? Should pass around the client pointer around other calls as well? I was trying to reinitiate the api call and destroy it in one function call.

Comment: Updated with example. You shouldn't need anything special here.